# intellij jump to html element by selector

Tags: html, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a big fan of IntelliJ. One thing I love about it is being able to jump to a file or method. Sometimes when I'm in an HTML file, though, I wish I had the ability to hit a hotkey and jump to an element in the HTML file by giving a jQuery selector, i.e. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> => `#form1` (and have it jump to `<form id=form1>` in the source...

Is this possible?

Comment: thanks, but yeah looking for an equivalent to the 'Navigate => file structure" type of approach...

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> works in HTML - hit the hotkey and start typing selector name.